# Where to place types / classes in Angular projects

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a project structure that looks like this:

```
e2e
src
  app
  assets
  modules
    core
    shared
    features
      one
      two 
      three
        components
          ...
        constants
          ...
        services
          ...
        three-routing.module.ts
        three.module.ts
```

`one` `two` and `three` all have the same inner structure, but I'm wondering where I should put some classes to represent e.g. `Three` and `ThreeRetrievalError`. Currently, I'm using an object `three` as a kind of any object where there is no type checking or enforcement.

Comment: While I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, "a kind of any object where there is no type checking or enforcement" already exists, and it's called `any`. Typescript happily shuts off all type checking when it sees an `any`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yes, I'm using `any` now and I don't want to any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) recommends making interfaces for declaring types/data models.

> Consider using an `interface` for data models.

Also, consider naming these interfaces without prefixing their names with `I` as it conflicts with TypeScripts naming conventions.

> Consider naming an `interface` **without an `I` prefix**.

There isn't any set guideline on where they should be kept though. It completely depends on how you like your files and folder structures to be.

That being said, I generally prefer keeping them into a folder of their own. So I guess, in folder `three`, you can create a `model` folder which will contain `three.model.ts` and `three-retrieval-error.model.ts` interface files. The naming of these files is derived from [this rule from the Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-01).

> Do follow a pattern that describes the symbol's feature then its type. The recommended pattern is `feature.type.ts`.